# One Avocado, 2 trees, separate pots

Tags: identification, avocado

Recently one of my avocado seeds broke in half.  Both halves rooted and now I have two very healthy trees in separate pots. They are five months old, 18" tall and look slightly different.  One has much larger leaves. What is this called?

Comment: Hi Robert, welcome to the site.  Could you post a picture?

Comment: Some pics would be nice.   Well done on getting 2 trees off 1 seed.  I am not sure why this has happened, what you are seeing or if it is indeed the case, but I do wonder if it relates to *apical dominance* and how the seed split (which Wikipedia defines as "s the phenomenon whereby the main, central stem of the plant is dominant over (i.e., grows more strongly than) other side stems; on a branch the main stem of the branch is further dominant over its own side twigs. )

Comment: I've tried to upload a picture of them side by side.  It says too big to send

Answer (score 2):

Avocado is a dicotyledon, meaning that the seed contains a couple of sections and produces two initial leaves rather unlike the subsequent leaves that appear. In common with chestnuts for example the seed sections contain a lot of fatty substances to nourish the infant plant as it becomes established, and this young plant draws heavily on those resources irrespective of the fertility of the soil it is growing in. The infant plant needs water, of course, and so will establish roots as well as drawing nutrients from the seed.

So one hypothesis would be that when the seed broke apart into two pieces, one of them received a much larger portion than the other, and therefore enjoys much more nutrient resources and is better able to withstand changes in environmental and soil conditions, resulting in a much healthier offspring compared to its sibling.